# Solution of equation of the form $n = 1234a + 56b + 7c$

Tags: diophantine-equations

I have $n = 1234a + 56b + 7c$.

Is there a way to check if a triplet $(a,b,c)$ exists, such that all three are non-negative?

Comment: What is the constraint, if any, on $n$?

Comment: See the [coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem).

Comment: n < 10^10 as given

Comment: @Arthur can you explain how to relate the coin problem to this

Comment: You can ignore $b$ - do you see why?

Comment: certainly $n<1234$ must be a multiple of $7$...

Comment: @Joffan no, can u please explain

Comment: $56=8\times 7$ so just increase $c$ by $8\times b$ and set $b=0$

Comment: @gt6989b 1359257 = 1234x1101 + 56 x 11 + 7x1
here
1101 is not a multiple of 7

Comment: You can relate the coin problem to this by saying "I have coins worth $1234$, $56$ and $7$. What values can I make from that?" Note that $a, b, c$ in this interpretation tells you how many you have of each coin.

Comment: @SayanGhosh this $n > 1234$...

Answer (score 3):

Essentially, as [Arthur](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/15500/arthur) mentions in the comments, this is a version of the [Coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem), finding out which values $n$ can be achieved using coins of value $1234, 56,$ and $7$.

The coin of value $56$ (and hence the variable $b$) does not change which values of $n$ are possible, as any value of $b$ can also be achieved by modifying the value of $c$ (since $7 \mid 56$). This simplifies the analysis to a two coin problem for which the answer is well-described in the wikipedia article.

However to go through the process, it's apparent that only multiples of $7$ are possible for  $n<1234$. Above that, since $1234 \equiv 2 \bmod 7$, values of $n \equiv k \in \{0,2\} \bmod 7$ are possible up to $2468$, which then opens up $n\equiv 4 \bmod 7$, etc until $6\times 1234 = 7404$ fills the last gap of $n \equiv 5 \bmod 7$. The $6$ values prior to that are also achievable, of course, so the largest number for which there is no non-negative $(a,b,c)$ combination possible is $n=7404-7 = 7397$.

Comment: If the constant $56$ in the problem were replaced with some other number roughly the same size but *not* divisible by $7$ - say, $65$ - then this would mean the variable $a$ could be disregarded since any multiple of $1234$ could easily be comprised of a suitable combination of the two smaller constants.